# Segue To Same View Controller Programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to segue to the same view controller in Swift?  There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532896/xcode-6-push-segue-to-same-view-controller) for this in Objective-C but I can't convert it to Swift

UPDATE: I was able to push to the same viewcontroller but it immediately errors because it doesn't recognize the objects that were created on the storyboard

```
let aViewController:myVC = myVC()
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(aViewController, animated:false)
```

On the Load of the new(same) view controller it errors on the first line:

```
myText.editable = false;
```

Comment: try self.viewDidLoad(), it automatically relaod the same viewcontroller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Is their a way I can pass parameters when calling the load again?  I initially load this view using prepareforsegue and I pass over parameters

Comment: if you use this concept the total viewcontroller allocated the memory, in here use NSUserDefault, else use local DB value

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I noticed if I use this method,  my memory usage continues to double after each time viewdidload is called.  Then the memory drops to normal usage after opening a different viewcontroller

Comment: can @DevTonio can you remove the UPvote for my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set an identifier for your UIViewController in the storyboard. Then instantiate it using that my identifier:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
```

If you want to set variables, make sure to cast `vc`. This example will help you know how many levels deep you are on the same controller:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootViewController") as! MyRootViewController
vc.level = self.level + 1
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik wherever OP was doing this: `let aViewController:myVC = myVC()`

Comment: @Rage thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

I don't do much in swift, but looking at that answer, using `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated:true)`
 should work.

Comment: doesn't work got this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported

Comment: You can't push the same instance (ie `self`) - you need to instantiate a new Instance from your storyboard

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks,  I got it to push to the same view controller but it immediately errors because it doesn't recognize the objects that were originally created on the storyboard.  Says there nil? for example I'm setting a textview.editable to false and it errors due to optional nil

Comment: How are you creating the new instance?

Comment: Thanks, `self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` is exactly what did it for me after instantiating the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

First you connect your button for reloading with ViewController and give segue identifier a name (for instance "yourIdentifier")

Then you need to use:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier"{
self.viewDidLoad()
}
```

This should help.